# Deploy ASP.NET Core to Azure Web App Service Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I am encountering an issue when publishing my application from Visual Studio.

[image]

I have added multiple Application Settings to figure out the error but can't seem to get a detailed error page.

[image]

I also have checked out the FREB logs and all I can find is a 500 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Edit `web.config` file in root of your project, set `stdoutLogEnabled` ti `true`
2. Check for `logs` folder in Azure (you need `D:\home\logs`, while your site located at `D:\home\site\wwwroot\`).

You may use [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) for both tasks.